# home page troubles in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I am having trouble in changing IE homepage. Everytime I change my home page to google.com or default it changes my home page into annoying one called **http://go.speedbit.com/?pid=s**   What the heck this? Also this thing is now trasfered into my Firefox browser. I don't know what that search bar is it is neither Bing nor Google. Could any one help me. I am using **IE 11** also **firefox latest version**

I update Windows *Important Updates* but *Optional Updates*

PC Specs:

**Windows 7 64bit**

**Aspire E1 431**

Comment: Looking around, that seems to be a download accelerator. You've got adware, but not a real virus. I suggest migrating this question to [SU].

Comment: @S.L.Barth I wouldn't be so sure it's "not a real virus". Sometimes adware is deployed through viruses for great benefit of l33t hax0r through affiliate programs.

Comment: Try running malwarebytes... but where has the user76506 gone? Has the account been deleted already?